# How to retrieve view id from application compiled and obfuscated by proguard?

Tags: android, resources, proguard, robotium, android-view

I'm writing tests for application that is compiled and obfuscated. Currently to access `View`
 I use Id form `/res/values/public.xml`

```
View myView = solo.getView(0x7f0b0030);
solo.clickOnView(((LinearLayout) (myView)).getChildAt(3));
```

This approach is valid only util application is not recompiled.

Is there any way to acces view by `Id` without having `R` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access ID of a resource by name using [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class.

For example:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", "drawable", "com.my_package");
```

The same trick should work for layout as well.

Comment: It worked but I used fully qualified name: `getIdentifier("my_package:id/my_layout", null, null)`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no method to access Id without R file.

If you came to know about solution please share your finding so that other can also benefitted.